# why the kmalloc return fail when there is free physical address but return success after dropping page caches

Tags: memory, memory-management, kernel

The machine's status is describe as blow:

the machine has 96 physical memory. And the real use memory is about 64G, and the page cache use about 32G. we also use the swap area, at that time we have about 10G(we set the swap max size to 32G). At that moment, we find xfs report

`Apr 29 21:54:31 w-openstack86 kernel: XFS: possible memory allocation deadlock in kmem_alloc (mode:0x250)`

after reading the source code. This message is display from this line

`ptr = kmalloc(size, lflags);
    if (ptr || (flags & (KM_MAYFAIL|KM_NOSLEEP)))
      return ptr;
    if (!(++retries % 100))
      xfs_err(NULL,
    "possible memory allocation deadlock in %s (mode:0x%x)",
          __func__, lflags);
    congestion_wait(BLK_RW_ASYNC, HZ/50);`

The error is cause by the kmalloc() function, there is not enough memory in the system. But there is still 32G page cache.

So I run

`echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`

to drop the page cache.

Then the system is fine. But I really don't know the reason.
Why after I run drop_caches operation the kmalloc() function will success? I think even we use whole physical memory, but we only use 64 real momory, the 32G memory are page cache, further we have enough swap space. So why the kernel don't flush the page cache or the swap to reserved the kmalloc operation.

Comment: Hi @baotiao, did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @pjay_ yes.  the main reason cause the problem is that even though we have enough memory, but the memory is fragment. when xfs alloc memory, it will always wiht GFP_NOFS flags, so this alloc_pages() can't have any operation relate with filesystem, this means that we can't flush page cache data to filesystem. and echo 3 > drop_cache is external operation, it don't this limitation